# When working with an already made website, how do you know which file to edit to change something?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

Let's say I'm building a website and using an already made Wordpress theme. Say it's a pretty complex theme and there's a lot of folders and files. If I wanted to change something specific, like text, or an image, or something that happens in Javascript/jQuery, and the change that I want is not an option in the themes control panel, what do I do? I know I have to go into the files but how do I know which file to go to? Lately, I've just download the theme to my desktop and use the windows search companion and type in the field that says "a word or phrase in the file." Sometimes it comes up and sometimes it doesn't. For CSS changes I usually use Firebug and click on the element, but many times I want to change the HTML/PHP/Javascript. I feel like I'm doing it the wrong way and there's an easier way that I'm missing.

Comment: Have you tried using your browser's inspector to see all of the resources that are loaded on the page and where they come from?

Comment: does the inspector tell me which file its in?

Comment: As far as javascript/jquery goes, Chrome can tell you a lot of information about all of the loaded files. Among those is a list of javascript files (and other resources) that the page loads. I'd recommend having a poke around the inspector.

Comment: I use Mozilla, can I do the same thing?

Comment: Mozilla is a company, not a web browser :) Yes, *Firefox* has similar features, though I've always felt that Chrome's implementation was cleaner/easier to use.

Comment: You can use firebug in Firefox but as @CezaryWojcik mentioned Chrome is lot easier to use and understand code flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned **WordPress theme** so I will specifically try to answer this question for editing WordPress theme.

When it comes to WordPress, everything is very structured and well organized. If theme written following standard practices then each component has its specific file. If you are familiar with WordPress theme structure and want to change php code or say a static part then all you need to do is locate the component file say `sidebar.php`, `home.php`, `single-{type}.php`, `header.php` and many similar files. http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Now if you want to edit something that is shown in right/left side of page as sidebar then chances of finding it in `sidebar.php` are maximum. Similarly to change something on home page try looking for `home.php`, for posts it could be `single-post.php`.

Many a times what you are looking to change might need a tweak in widgets. In this case, process remains same as theme you just need to look in different folder.

**Javascript**: For editing javascript, beautify the code if it came minified. When you have code ready much of js debugging can be done using firebug/Developer Console in chrome. Best way is to put breakpoints at relevant position and then inspect code behavior. You will be able to locate code block that you need to tweak to achieve what you want.

**CSS**: Create a child theme and then use it override default theme properties.

Comment: That's the thing though, lately the past 5 themes I've bought and used all have so many more files than the conventional ones like header, footer, sidebar, there's so many archive and single files and then there's subfolders with even more templates in them. I understand what you're saying and it's definitely helpful, but sometimes these themes that I use aren't organized/structured. Is there any kind of shortcut to see what file produces that code? Would it be a good idea to create a plug in or software that does something like that?

Comment: I understand your pain, themes are getting complex with each passing day. However this is approach I have followed in my last 5 year stint with wordpress and have seen many other developers doing the same. IMHO after view code sessions you get a fair idea of where to look for and start finding things quickly.

There might be a better way but I am not aware of any.

Comment: Thanks, just clearing my mind that I'm not missing some kind of easy quick finding solution is helpful - I will pay more attention to the directory

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `grep` in PowerShell, Cygwin, etc.

```
grep -lir "a word or phrase in the file." *
```

*edit*: [Emulating Grep in Powershell](http://www.mickelson.org/2007/12/06/emulating-grep-in-powershell/)